# Inject using spring lots of beans instances in a map/list without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How can I inject in a Map (or a List) of a java bean , instances of some different classes using spring but without using xml configurations (we should use only annotations) ? I want to be able to specify the particular instances to be injected in that map by name or by implementing class

Instances will be declared using something like this:

> @Component   ("instanceA") 
>   public class A implements I {
>   ...
>   }

PS For simplification we may assume first that all instances implement the same interface, but this will not always be true...

Comment: your question seems incomplete, can you please add some more information for eg on what condition you want your beans to be selected. Also if you want beans to be added in a list they have to implement same interface else the map has to be of Object type.

Comment: There's no general condition to select the beans, I want to be able to cherry pick each particular instance based on name or the name of the  implementing class. They will all implement the same interface (this is the usual usage)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bean factory to get access to all necessary beans

```
@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
```

`beansOfType.getBeansOfType()` returns a map `BeanName -> Bean`.

You just need to know bean names, which you want to "inject."
List necessaryBeanNames;

Then you can take only necessary beans.

```
Map<String, YourInterface> beansOfType = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(YourInterface.class);

List<YourInterface> necessaryBeanNames.stream().map(b-> beansOfType.get(b)).filter(b -> b != null).collect(toList());
```

Comment: I want to cherry pick instances not select them all

Comment: will `@Qualifier` help you?

Comment: I would prefer to load the beans by the implementing class rather than by name cause it is more statically typed.

Comment: You are right, but `getBeansOfType()` gives you all beans implementing the type. How you are going to filter them?

Answer (score 0):

there is no already present annotation which can do this for you but you can use @Bean and @Qualifier to get the desired results.

```
@Bean
public List<YourInterface> getList(@Qualifier("yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl1") YourInterface yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl1, @Qualifier("yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl2") YourInterface yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl2) {
    return Arrays.asList(new YourInterface[]{yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl1, yourCherryPickedInterfaceImpl2});
}
```